# Mozilla firefox doesn't retain CSS when printing

Tags: css, printing, mozilla

In my application I am trying to print a page on click of the print button.
It shows perfectly in print preview, but in print the CSS is not maintained in `Mozilla Firefox`. However, it prints as shown in `Chrome` and `Internet explorer`.

I can't attach the snapshot because data is confidential here.

Below is the code I used for printing..

```
function PrintWithServices() {
            // for print
            var printCRMDetails = new $("#DivToPrint");
            var printServiceDetails = new $("#DivServicesToPrint");
            var mywindow = window.open("", "popup", "width=1000,height=600,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes," +
                        "toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0");
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
            mywindow.document.write('<link href="../../Content/CSSForPrint.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body><div id="#main">');
            mywindow.document.write('<center><span class="header-title-without-margin">CRM Doctor Request Details </span></center>');
            mywindow.document.write($(printCRMDetails).html());
            mywindow.document.write($(printServiceDetails).html());
            mywindow.document.write('</div></body></html>');

            mywindow.print();
        }
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `document.write`. I suspect the `document.write` might interfere with Firefox's ability to load the resource in time. Without the `mywindow.print` it would be able to start loading the CSS file as soon as this function was completed, but now it simply hasn't done that yet before it has to start printing.

Comment: Ya problem is this only. you @MrLister got it. But now how I give print option that it executed after loading is completed. I am not able to do so... Please suggest..